# MOSS 2007 SPItemEventProperties values of fields accessed via display name or internal name

Tags: 2007, document-library, event-receivers, spfield, internal-name

I need to access the before and after field values for the list item corresponding to an event receiver in MOSS 2007. The name of the field is `Annual Salary` and the InternalName is `Annual_x0020_Salary`. I used the following code to determine the value of the field:

```
properties.BeforeProperties[properties.ListItem.Fields["Annual Salary"].InternalName] // yields null
properties.ListItem.Fields["Annual Salary"].InternalName // yields Annual_x0020_Salary
properties.BeforeProperties["Annual Salary"])); // yields 100000
```

I read that fetching the value via the internal name is best practice towards future-proofing the code base. But according to what I am seeing, I am not even able to access the value using the internal name. On the contrary, I am able to access the value via the display name. Is this expected behavior? This is for a document library, if that makes any difference.